# Making C floats precise?

Tags: c, floating-point

In C, when a float is set,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float temp = 98.6f;
    printf("%f\n", temp);
    return 0;
}
```

It always seems to get some kind of rounding error,

```
98.599998
```

But when I make it more precise,

```
float temp = 96.600000f;
```

It still prints a different number. How is this supposed to be solved?

Comment: Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Also see [fixed-point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) - not to replace floats in general, but it's another approach to some problems.

Comment: Another good reference: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: If you think that is bad, how you compile your code can also change these things. Specifically it might use 80bits or 64bits for the double representation.

Answer (score 10):

> It still prints a different number. How is this supposed to be solved?

By using a different data type, if you want precise *decimal* values.

Binary floating point numbers *are* precise - it's just they're precise *binary* values.

Likewise decimal is imprecise if you want to represent numbers in base 3, for example. There's no exact binary representation of 0.1 decimal, just as there's no exact decimal representation of "one third".

It's all a matter of working out what your requirements are, and using a data type which matches them. For precise decimal values, you're probably best off using a third-party library... or keep an integer that you know is logically scaled by 100, or 10,000 or whatever.

Comment: @EdHeal: A value of a floating point type where the "point" being floated is a binary point. For example, one eighth is 0.001 in binary, which might be represented as "mantissa 1, with an exponent of -3" (depending on exact representation).

Comment: @JonSkeet so it's like decimals in base 2? So while `1100` is 12 in decimals, `1100.01` is 12.25 in decimals?

Comment: @tkbx: Yes. Except that the value is represented as two integers - a *mantissa* and an *exponent*. You might find it useful to read my article on binary floating point numbers in .NET - it's at least *very similar* to what you'll find in C. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Not quite. The representation is akin to scientific notation. The mantissa is between 0 and 0.5 (in old money with a bit for negative - now extra for NaN etc). That decimal (or binary) point is not floating. The exponent is the power to raise that to. 
But the overall value does have a floating point in the sense of its accuracy. In your example an eight is 0.5 * 2 ^ -2

PS: Wrote floating point arithmetic in 6520A assembly (oh what fun)

Comment: @EdHeal: No, the mantissa is always an integer in every floating point type format I've ever seen. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point for example. "Finite numbers, which may be either base 2 (binary) or base 10 (decimal). Each finite number is described by three integers: s = a sign (zero or one), c = a significand (or 'coefficient'), q = an exponent." (And under the wikipedia entry for Mantissa, we have "The significand of floating-point number or scientific notation" - so they're just synonyms.)

Comment: @EdHeal: Now normalization gets involved in IEEE-754 of course, which is why I added the "depending on the exact representation" part - but the fundamental idea is normally to use integers.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format and consider the line (for example) 0 01111 0000000001 = 1 + 2−10 = 1.0009765625 (next biggest float after 1) - Is 2 ^ -10 an integer (the mantissa part?)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Floating point numbers is akin to scientific notation. i.e. the numbers in the mantissa range between -10 and +10 (with the fractions in between) RAISED TO THE POWER OF 10 to the exponent. How would you write down PI in a limited number of digits and using the same space (squares on a sheet of graph paper) the speed of light.

Comment: @EdHeal: Repeating it doesn't make it any more true. The part about representing irrational numbers is irrelevant to the discussion about whether the mantissa in a floating point number is represented as an integer or not. Did you read the wikipedia article?

Comment: @JonSkeet - You can think of a byte as a character, yes/no, integer, whatever. At the endof the day it is a series of ons and offs. The semantics of this is up to up. Is it a letter, number, pixel, .... But in this context the mantissa is interpreted (understood) as contained the fraction part - along with sigh/NaN etc) and the exponent is understood to be a integer. But they are just bytes - series of ons and offs.

Comment: @EdHeal: No, both are considered integers (at least in IEEE754), and the mantissa is shifted left or right based on the exponent (which is often offset itself). Again, please read the wikipedia article - or my own article linked in the fourth comment. Saying "the semantics of this are up to you" is just avoiding being precise about communication - semantics are everything.

Comment: So how do you represent an 1/3 with a mantissa and a exponent (lets use base 10 makes life easier for both of us)

Comment: @EdHeal: You use 3333333333333 (for as large a value as you can, based on how many bits are available) and a suitable exponent to shift it by. It won't be precise, of course - a point I made in the answer. It will just be "as close as can be represented in that type."

Comment: So what is the mantissa and exponent normalized on your scientific calculator.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Then try 33.765

Comment: @EdHeal: I have no idea what you mean by that question. You don't get to *see* the raw mantissa and exponent on a calculator... nor do I see the relevance of 33.765 (which would be represented as 33765 with an effective exponent of -3 for example). I really don't see what point you're trying to make with all of this.

Comment: @JonSkeet - But the mantissa represents a value between -10 to 10.

Comment: @EdHeal: No, it really doesn't. Just because that's how scientific notation is usually used in documents doesn't make it the logical choice for floating point representations in a computer. (You *could* create a floating point representation like that, but it's not a commonly used one.)

Comment: @EdHeal: If you want yet *more* documentary evidence, let's move away from IEEE-754 and on to `System.Decimal` in .NET. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) "The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the 96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. The scaling factor is implicitly the number 10, raised to an exponent ranging from 0 to 28."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33725/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-ed-heal)

Comment: IEEE 754-2008 generally treats the significand (not mantissa; mantissas are logarithmic, significands are linear) as a digit string of the form “d[0].d[1]d[2]…d[p-1]” (where subscripts would be used if the typography were available in a comment), per IEEE 754-2008 clause 3.3. Naturally, there is a mathematically equivalent formulation where the significand is always an integer, and that may be more useful for various proofs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thank you for the clarification. It certainly makes more sense to me to think of it as an integer: we know how to represent an integer already in binary, so it feels odd to introduce another "intermediate" representation. Will edit to use "significand" instead of "mantissa" - although they're used interchangably elsewhere. (Oops - I see all of the mantissa discussion was actually in comments anyway...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I think of binary floating point numbers as radix 2 scientific notation, with bounded exponent range and number of significant bits. In those terms, the way IEEE 754 handles them seems very natural to me. In particular, the most significant bit is handled differently, so it makes a lot of sense to put the binary point between it and the rest of the significand.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: But with an integer significand it's still just "a number shifted by a number of bits". I guess I've just been coloured by the various pieces of documentation I linked to earlier, which *do* consider the significand as an integer. Ultimately it's just a matter of how much you shift by, of course...

Answer (score 6):

This is a fundamental limitation of representing decimal numbers in binary form. Binary floating point numbers are expressed in powers of 2 while decimal numbers are expressed in powers of 10, and C's `float` is simply unable to exactly represent all the decimal numbers.

Your example number, 96.1 can be written as:

```
96.1 = 9*10^1 + 9*10^0 + 1*10^-1
```

To represent this in binary, you can get the integer 96 just fine:

```
96 = 1*2^6 + 1*2^5
```

but representing the 0.1 is problematic in base 2. The place values of the first few fractional places in binary are:

```
2^-1 = 0.5
2^-2 = 0.25
2^-3 = 0.125
2^-4 = 0.0625
2^-5 = 0.03125
2^-6 = 0.015625
2^-7 = 0.0078125
2^-8 = 0.00390625
2^-9 = 0.001953125
... and so on
```

So somehow you need to use a combination of these place values to add up to approximate 0.1 in decimal. So you would have to start with b0.0001 (d0.0625) as being the first place less than d0.1 and add some more of the smaller place values to get closer and closer to 0.1. For example:

```
b0.001      = d0.125      // too high, try lower
b0.0001     = d0.0625     // too low, so add smaller places
b0.00011    = d0.09375    // good, closer... rounding error is 0.0625
b0.000111   = d0.109375   // oops, a little high
b0.00011001 = d0.09765625 // getting better - how close do you need?
...
```

And so on - you get the idea. So the binary values can only approximate decimals due to the fundamental representation.

There are many articles on floating point rounding errors and representational limits. It is definitely worth doing some background reading on this topic.

There are a few ways to solve this problem:

- Use `float` but remain aware of the limitations and carefully design the algorithm to minimise rounding errors
- Use an exact decimal representation such as BCD (binary coded decimal), which is used in financial systems to avoid rounding errors
- Use a fixed data type, where numbers are expressed as fractions of integers, and only convert to floating point at the end of the calculation to display the result.

Comment: *Binary* floating point numbers are expressed in powers of two. It's entirely feasible to have non-binary floating point numbers - the idea of a floating point number is just that there's a mantissa and an exponent, which is interpreted in some base. For example, System.Decimal in .NET is a decimal floating point number.

Answer (score 4):

Adding trailing zeroes will never make a difference.

The problem is that 32-bit floating cannot precisely express `96.6`, period.

It isn't randomly picking digits to fill what you left out; it's rounding it to the closest number that it can express.

Answer (score 3):

It's platform-dependent, but usually a number like 98.6 can't be represented exactly.

What you can do is use `printf` precision specifiers like `"%.2f"` to "round" the number displayed.

Comment: +1 for "_usually_ a number like 98.6 can't be represented exactly".  Floating point _could_ be decimal and 98.6 would then be exact.  e. g. IEEE 754 decimal32.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple answer.  It has to do with how floats are represented in memory, but how we tend to think they can represent all real numbers.  They can't.  If you want to be precise with floats, think of less-than or greater-than ranges instead of trying to equate them.  In your example, try %f2.1  (or similar) to print out a smaller amount of digits to the right of the decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

The give away is the word **float**.

It is composed of a mantissa and an exponent. The value is the best representation that it can achieve in a limited number of bits (take pi for example).

So do not use equality as you get rounding errors. You can take steps to minimise them, but that requires a few lectures and a text book.

BTW - Do not use floats for money. Better use integers and compute things in cents/pennies/...

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why "98.6" can't be represented exactly. The key problem here isn't that it's floating point - it's that the point being floated is a *binary* point, whereas the source data is *decimal*.